# Composer Segmentation Fault when installing bundle on symfony 3

Tags: doctrine, composer-php, symfony

I am working with Symfony 3 framework and I would like to add a new bundle using GIT Bash console.

When I run the following command:

```
$ composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle
```

I get the following error:

**Using version ^1.1 for doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-eventmanager (3.0.1)
/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer: line 10:  6388 Segmentation fault      php "${dir}/composer.phar" "$@"**

Does anybody have any clue how can I fix this?

Thank you,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this as well?:

```
$ composer require doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle "^1.0"
```